# Submit a form using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to submit a form using jQuery. Can someone provide the code, a demo or an example link?

Answer (score 538):

It depends on whether you are submitting the form normally or via an AJAX call. You can find lots of information at [jquery.com](https://jquery.com/), including documentation with examples. For submitting a form normally, check out the [`submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) method to at that site. For [AJAX](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/), there are many different possibilities, though you probably want to use either the [`ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [`post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) methods. Note that `post()` is really just a convenient way to call the `ajax()` method with a simplified, and limited, interface.

A critical resource, one I use every day, that you should bookmark is [How jQuery Works](https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/). It has tutorials on using jQuery and the left-hand navigation gives access to all of the documentation.

Examples:

Normal

```
$('form#myForm').submit();
```

AJAX

```
$('input#submitButton').click( function() {
    $.post( 'some-url', $('form#myForm').serialize(), function(data) {
         // ... do something with response from server
       },
       'json' // I expect a JSON response
    );
});

$('input#submitButton').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some-url',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form#myForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
                   // ... do something with the data...
                 }
    });
});
```

Note that the `ajax()` and `post()` methods above are equivalent. There are additional parameters you can add to the `ajax()` request to handle errors, etc.

Answer (score 140):

You will have to use `$("#formId").submit()`.

You would generally call this from within a function.

For example:

```
<input type='button' value='Submit form' onClick='submitDetailsForm()' />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function submitDetailsForm() {
       $("#formId").submit();
    }
</script>
```

You can get more information on this on the [Jquery website](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit).

Comment: If you're using jQuery why would you use an inline onclick attribute?

Answer (score 84):

when you have an existing form, that should now work with jquery - ajax/post now you could:

- hang onto the submit - event of your form
- prevent default functionality of submit
- do your own stuff

  ```
  $(function() {
      //hang on event of form with id=myform
      $("#myform").submit(function(e) {

          //prevent Default functionality
          e.preventDefault();

          //get the action-url of the form
          var actionurl = e.currentTarget.action;

          //do your own request an handle the results
          $.ajax({
                  url: actionurl,
                  type: 'post',
                  dataType: 'application/json',
                  data: $("#myform").serialize(),
                  success: function(data) {
                      ... do something with the data...
                  }
          });

      });

  });
  ```

Please note that, in order for the `serialize()` function to work in the example above, all form elements need to have their `name` attribute defined.

Example of the form:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="http://example.com/do_recieve_request">

<input type="text" size="20" value="default value" name="my_input_field">
..
.
</form>
```

@PtF - the data is submitted using POST in this sample, so this means you can access your data via

```
 $_POST['dataproperty1']
```

, where dataproperty1 is a "variable-name" in your json.

here sample syntax if you use CodeIgniter:

```
 $pdata = $this->input->post();
 $prop1 = $pdata['prop1'];
 $prop1 = $pdata['prop2'];
```

Answer (score 74):

In jQuery I would prefer the following:

```
$("#form-id").submit()
```

But then again, you really don't need jQuery to perform that task - just use regular JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("form-id").submit()
```

Comment: @windmaomao I had the same issue. My jQuery ran all other functions, but would not submit the form. It worked by just using the document.getElementById method.

Answer (score 52):

From the manual: [jQuery Doc](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

```
$("form:first").submit();
```

Comment: It is batter to submit form by "id' than finding the first form and submit it. However it will works perfectly if there is only one form at a time.

Answer (score 28):

For information
if anyone use

```
$('#formId').submit();
```

**Do not something like this**

```
<button name = "submit">
```

It took many hours to find me that submit() won't work like this.

Comment: Typo on key word `"sumit"` makes it unclear if the typo is unintented in answer, or was related to the problem. Do you mean that a button named `"submit"` messes up jquery form submit()? Or do you mean the problem was that you gave the button _name_ submit instead of the standard `type="submit"`?

Comment: my intention was not to answer this question but to tell those who faced this problem. I think the problem is with button name without type defined, because I used onclick event to check some input before submit. If type=submit then form submit without my onclick event fire.

Comment: ```<button id= "submit">``` doesn't allow submit too

Answer (score 21):

Use it to submit your form using jquery.
Here is the link http://api.jquery.com/submit/

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        $( "#form" ).submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Though this is an old post, it's worth adding a type `button` to your button to ensure the form does not submit (as not all browsers treat buttons with no types the same way).

Comment: @Mikey Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 17):

this will send a form with preloader :

```
var a=$('#yourform').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'receiver url',
    data:a,
    beforeSend:function(){
        launchpreloader();
    },
    complete:function(){
        stopPreloader();
    },
    success:function(result){
         alert(result);
    }
});
```

i'have some trick to make a form data post reformed with random method http://www.jackart4.com/article.html

Comment: could you post the updated link?  The link above no longer works.

Answer (score 16):

```
$("form:first").submit();
```

See [events/submit](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit).

Answer (score 15):

Note that if you already installed a submit event listener for your form, the innner call to submit()

```
jQuery('#<form-id>').submit( function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    // maybe some validation in here
    if ( <form-is-valid> ) jQuery('#<form-id>').submit();
});
```

**won't** work as it tries to install a new event listener for this form's submit event (which fails). So you have to acces the HTML Element itself (unwrap from jQquery) and call submit() on this element directly:

```
    jQuery('#<form-id>').submit( function(e){ 
      e.preventDefault();
      // note the [0] array access:
      if ( <form-is-valid> ) jQuery('#<form-id>')[0].submit();
    });
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the jquery form plugin to submit using ajax aswell:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Answer (score 10):

Note that in Internet Explorer there are issues with dynamically created forms. A form created like this will not submit in IE (9):

```
var form = $('<form method="post" action="/test/Delete/">' +
             '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' + myid + '"></form>');
$(form).submit();
```

To get it working in IE create the form element and attach it before submitting like so:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
$(form).attr("action", "/test/Delete")
       .attr("method", "post");
$(form).html('<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' + myid + '" />');
document.body.appendChild(form);
$(form).submit();
document.body.removeChild(form);
```

Creating the form like in example 1 and then attaching it will not work - in IE9 it throws a JScript error `DOM Exception: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR (3)`

Props to Tommy W @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/6694054/694325

Answer (score 8):

```
jQuery("a[id=atag]").click( function(){

    jQuery('#form-id').submit();      

            **OR**

    jQuery(this).parents("#form-id").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 8):

The solutions so far require you to know the ID of the form.

Use this code to submit the form without needing to know the ID:

```
function handleForm(field) {
    $(field).closest("form").submit();
}
```

For example if you were wanting to handle the click event for a button, you could use

```
$("#buttonID").click(function() {
    handleForm(this);    
});
```

Answer (score 8):

If the button is located between the form tags, I prefer this version:

```
$('.my-button').click(function (event) {
    var $target = $( event.target );
    $target.closest("form").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

My approach was slightly different, change the button into submit button and then click

```
$("#submit").click(function (event) {
  $(this).attr("type", "submit");
  $(this).click();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

IE trick for dynamic forms:

```
$('#someform').find('input,select,textarea').serialize();
```

Answer (score 5):

you could use it like this :

```
  $('#formId').submit();
```

OR

```
document.formName.submit();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function  form_submit(form_id,filename){
    $.post(filename,$("#"+form_id).serialize(), function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

It will post the form data on your given file name via AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a generic solution so you don't have to add the code for every form. Use the jquery form plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) and add this code.

```
$(function(){
$('form.ajax_submit').submit(function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit();
            //validation and other stuff
        return false; 
});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do it like this :

```
$('#myform').bind('submit', function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score -2):

I have also used the following to submit a form (without actually submitting it) via Ajax:

```
  jQuery.get("process_form.php"+$("#form_id").serialize(), {}, 
    function() {
      alert("Okay!"); 
    });
```

Comment: this isn't anything like a submit(). for one thing submit() uses POST semantics, you're using a GET