# How to submit a form with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, submit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Submit a form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

```
$('#form')
```

Supposed the jQuery Object of the form is available.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('#form').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a lot of form ajaxery, you may be [interested in this plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). You can wire up your form on document ready and it will handle the ajaxing:

```
$('#form').ajaxForm();
```