# How to post a form using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, jqueryform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [submit a form using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

Hello friends

How can I submit a form using jquery. My form contain one file field also how can I post my form with out reloading the whole page. Any body can help me with some sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'servletToUSe',
    data: {
        "fieldValue": $('#fieldName').val()
    },
    success: function () {
        //response handler
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As always [nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/) provide a great tutorial for this - [Submit A Form Without Page Refresh using jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)

Comment: I'm not sure it will work with files.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way is to use jQuery Form plugin, which can be found on http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Then in the simplest option you just need to put below mention code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#your_form_id').ajaxForm();
});
```

See the plugin's documentation for further details.