# FF - doesn't work $('#target').submit();

Tags: jquery, firefox, file-upload

If I try to invoke `$('#basicForm').submit();` where `basicForm` is

```
<form method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1:6789/BasicUploadFile/" id="basicForm"
    enctype="multipart/form-data" target="basicuploader_iframe">
  <div id="basicFilesInputContainer" class="basicInputContainer">
    <div class="mybutton btn-green basicAddButton" id="basicAddButton">Add file(s)</div>
    <input type="file" name="myFiles" size="200" multiple class="basicInputButton" id="basicUploadFile">
  </div>
  <div id="basicUploadFileSubmit">
    <div class="basicSubmitButton mybutton btn-blue" >Upload files</div>
    <input type="submit" id="basicUploadFileSubmitBtn" style="visibility:hidden" >
  </div>
  <input type="reset" class="mybutton btn-red basicDelButton" value="Delete files" name="resetBtn" id="basicUploadFileReset">
</form>
```

It works fine in every browser (Chrome, Opera, Safari), but in FireFox it doesn't work. Even more it crashes FF!!! Is it FF bug? Thanks.

Comment: Where do you invoke it? What does FireBug Console tell's you?

Comment: "Crashes" FF as in, it hangs your browser? What FF version? The problem is hardly related to the single line of code which you showed.

Comment: As much as I can test it, it works for me on FF nightly on Linux.

Comment: FireBug doesn't say anything. As I said FF crashes. I use FF v12.0

Comment: Sorry guys! I was trying to invoke `$ ('#basicUploadFileSubmitBtn').click();`. Just forgot refresh page. But `$ ('#basicUploadFileSubmitBtn').click();` doesn't work at all! If someone know why I'll appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Firefox 13 beta 6 works for me. It works with `.click()` and  `$('#basicUploadFileSubmitBtn').trigger("click");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out this related question: [Submit a form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

I think the original way you wrote the question is correct. You should be using:

```
$("#basicForm").submit();
```

to trigger the submit action.

Alternatively, some more info about what you're submitting could help. It looks like you're trying to test an upload script on your localhost. I found a post here where a user noted that FF 12 seems to upload files more slowly than other browsers: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/927382

Comment: What's the difference between your code and the code in the question?