# Capture the value of a Password input type using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, authentication

The goal is to log into a site and not have to refresh the screen. I am using a a textbox to capture the email/username and a password box (input type="password") for the password. Then, ideally, I want to pass those values back to a web service for authentication using JQuery/AJAX. The problem I am experiencing, however, is that the JQuery is unable to access the value of the Password field, always passing back an empty string instead of the password.

I understand the security implications of being able to access someone's password via script, but is there a way, some workaround or technique, to accomplish what I am attempting?

Thank You,
G

**UPDATE :**
How do I get points deducted for asking a question? Is this that stupid of a question? Although the answer may prove worthy of a couple of "DOH" deductions ... As it turns out there were TWO password fields on the form, each with the same ID. I was getting the value from the empty one. I appreciate everyone's responses and help however. As always I was led to some helpful links and information.

Comment: Can you show your code? jQuery IS able to access the value of password field. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/a8uRT/)

Comment: Check out this for you answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery

Comment: @Bondye - have you tried? It is not disabled

Comment: @Bondye — Nonsense. Security is provided via the same origin policy and from add-ons having to be installed manually. There's no need to block access to the value from all of JavaScript, so browsers don't.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing special about password inputs as far as reading the value with JS is concerned. See [this live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HyLfx/) for proof.

If the field isn't being submitted, then something is wrong with your basic approach.

Perhaps you are calling `serialize()` but haven't given the input a name. It is impossible to know what the actual problem is without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="password" name="password" />
```

and javascript

```
$(function(){
  $.post('your-url', {password: $("input[name='password']").val()}, callback(info){
   // proccess success
  },
  'json' // or other dataType
});
```

read more http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

and PHP maybe:

```
if(isset($_POST["password"])){
 //proccess info server
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just submit the entire form via AJAX, you don't need to take the individual values from the form, put post is as it is.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has no problems in accessing password fields value - [check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/NgeDq/).

You will have security issues as long as you connect to your webservice over plain `HTTP` instead of `HTTPS`, so consider [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) authorization mode if you cannot support a secure protocol.