# Treat a span as input element

Tags: html, css, forms, icons

Is it possible to use a span to trigger input?

e.g.

```
<div class='btn'>
    <span type="submit" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe000;"></span>
</div>
```

I may be missing something blindingly obvious but I basically just want to use an icon font as a send button.

Thanks!

Comment: A send button? Like to submit a form? You can use JavaScript and bind the click handler to the span.

Comment: You can use javascript to do this; however, why not just use CSS to re-design a normal submit-button instead?

Comment: Why not just redesign a normal submit ^

Comment: Hi, because I want to specifically use an icon e.g. a paper plane, that when you click submits the form

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't put `type="submit"` , but you can execute some Javascript codes when you click on it.

**JQuery**

```
<span id="mySpan"> </span>

$("#mySpan").click(function(){

    //stuff here

});
```

**Javascript**

```
<span id="mySpan" onclick="MyClick()"> </span>

function MyClick()
{

  //stuff here

}
```

**SPAN working as a Submit Button**

```
<input type="text" id="usernameInputField />
<input type="email" id="emalInputField />
<span id="mySpan" onclick="Register()"></span>
```

Now in Javascript..

```
function Register()
{
   //First you need to do some validation
   var username = document.getElementById("usernameInputField").value;
   var email = document.getElementById("emailInputField").value;
   //Password, Gender, etc...
   //Then start doing your validation the way you like it...
   /*if(password.length<6)
     {
         alert("Password is too short");
         return false;
     }
   */
   //Then when everything is valid, Post to the Server
   //This is a PHP Post Call
   $.post("Register.php",{ username:username,email:email } ,function(data) {
       //more codes
   });
}
```

Comment: Ok I'll look up how to initiate a submit with jQuery. The existing input code looks like this <input type="submit" value="Send">

Comment: @SparrwHawk For this you need to use JQuery's Post, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Thanks Ali, can you give an example for a submit button?

Comment: @SparrwHawk I provided an example, I hope this is what you asked for. Check these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example

Answer (score 22):

If you have a form, you can just call `myform.submit()`

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="action.php">
    <div>
        <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
        <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe000;" onclick="myform.submit()">Submit</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess Olaf's answer is simpler than Ali's. But there is a slight problem when you wish to verify if the form has been submitted, in your php script, when using Olaf's solution.

To circomvent this problem, just add a hidden input to confirm the form's been sent.

```
<form name="myform" method="post" action="action.php">
    <div>
        <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="gustav" value="1"/>
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
        <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe000;" onclick="myform.submit()">Submit</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Then, in your PHP, just look for `if($_POST['gustav']){ ...` to confirm the form has been sent.

That way, you can have multiple forms on one page, all gathered by the same php script, still using Olaf's solution to trigger the submit.