# jQuery plugin for submiting Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a Form like this in asp Classic ..

```
<form method="post" name="AddItemForm" id="AddItemForm" action="/files/includes/CartControl.asp" style="display:inline;">
```

// bunch of Hidden Fields.

Then a SUBMIT button.

action of the form takes all the hidden fields and then after processing them **redirects** user to a CART page.

now what I want to do is....I want user to click on ADD TO CART button, however I want user to stay on the product page while form submits to a new window (not a javascript new window...something like lightbox/colorbox/fancybox DIV etc).

I looked into many jQuery plugins but could not get a satisfied answer...which plugin is BEST for my case? any simple example?

basicly I want to submit to a new overlay div and within that DIV redirect user to a new page to show Product Info.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery), the code from one of the answers:

```
$('input#submitButton').click( function() {
    $.post( 'some-url', $('form#myForm').serialize(), function(data) {
         ... do something with response from server
       },
       'json' // I expect a JSON response
    );
});
```

In "do something with response" you can take the data or url and load it into an overlay div.
If it's a URL, you can use jquery .load :

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

If it's html (or data which you wrap in html), just do

```
$('#result').html(theHTML)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are looking for some functionality for asynchronous form submission. There is this [jQuery AJAX Form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) that provides AJAX functionality for forms. You will have something like:

```
$('#AddItemForm').submit( function() {
    // Submit asynchronously
    $( this ).ajaxSubmit( function() {
        // Form processing is done
        // Redirect to the shopping cart page
    });

    // Show a modal or a fancy "please wait" message

    // Prevent default submission
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way (in my view) is to add target attribute to the form which will open new window while the current page won't chage...

Comment: i really want to stay away from javaScript POP UP windows.

Comment: @highwingers why not to use modal dialog then?

Comment: i never used modal dialog...examples/samples please?

Comment: This is called `Jquery UI Modal Dialog`. Google for this.

Comment: you cannot "... redirects user to a CART page." and " ...  stay on the product page" if both ARE NOT the same page. You could either redirect OR stay. AND is a nonsense in this case, unless both are one and the same page