# jquery form submit does not work after using a load function

Tags: php, jquery, dom

I have an index.html page which, using jquery, calls  somepage.php residing within the same site to load the contents of this index.html page.

So this is the intended page load sequence:
index.html -> somepage.php -> submit.php (if submit button is clicked)

The index.html has only the "main-div" and no contents as such. When the somepage.php is called, the "main-div" contents are loaded by running the php script. The main-div contains a sub div with a small form with a submit button. Using jQuery,I see if the submit button is clicked, and when clicked, the submit.php script is called.

This is the barebone code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('document').ready(function(){            

                $("#main-div").load("http://www.someurl.com/somepage.php");

                $('#item-submit').click(function(){
                    jsURL = $('#input').val();
                    submit(jsURL);

                });

                function submit(jsURL){
                    $.get(
                        'http://www.someurl.com/submit.php',    
                        {   item: jsURL   },
                        function(data){
                            if(data=="success")
                            {
                            $('#submit-status').html(data);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            $('#submit-status').html(data);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }


            });
        </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="main-div"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now the issue:
The index.html page loads with everything displayed correctly (the small form with the submit button, all other main-div contents, everything is displayed). However, the submit button does not call the submit.php script, meaning I believe that the jQuery code corresponding to the click event is not being registered.

I am fairly new to jQuery. Does this have something to do with how I have "ordered" the code in the jQuery .ready()? Something to do with the DOM not being ready before the  function is called, or maybe an issue with the .load() in jQuery?

Comment: where is '#item-submit' on your html, Is it in the returned response?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery can help you

Comment: @MohamedAli - yes, item-submit is in the returned response from the somepage.php script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#main-div").load("http://www.someurl.com/somepage.php",function(){
        $("#main-div").on('click', '#item-submit', function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           var jsURL = $('#input').attr('value');
           submit(jsURL);
        });
        });
});

function submit(jsURL){
                    $.ajax({
                    url:'http://www.someurl.com/submit.php',
                    type :'GET',
                    success: function(data){
                    $('#submit-status').html(data);
                    }
                    });

                }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){            
    $("#main-div").load("http://www.someurl.com/somepage.php");

    $("#main-div").on('click', '#item-submit', function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           var jsURL = $('#input').val();
           submit(jsURL);
    });

    function submit(jsURL){
      $.get('http://www.someurl.com/submit.php', {item: jsURL}, function(data){
           $('#submit-status').html(data);
      });
    }
});
```

1. Do not quote the document
2. `load()` is a shortcut for `$.ajax`, and it's async, so `#item-submit` does'nt exist when you attach the event handler, you need a delegated event handler for that.
3. If it's really a submit button inside a form, make you sure you prevent the default action so the form does'nt get submitted.

Comment: You may quote `document`, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel - Sure, it does work even with the quotes, so Sizzle probably figures it out, but it does in fact matter as dropping the quotes will reference the document directly.

Comment: Or use shorthand `$(function(){`.

Comment: Thank You, @Marcel Korpel and adeneo

Answer (score 2):

The [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function works asynchronously. With your code `#item-submit` is not yet there when you try to bind the event handler.

Bind the event handler on succes:

```
$("#main-div").load("http://www.someurl.com/somepage.php", function () {
    $('#item-submit').click(function () {
        jsURL = $('#input').val();
        submit(jsURL);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`load` loads the data asynchronously, which means time by the time you are assigning a click handler on submit button the button itself might not be yet on the page. To overcome this you have two options:

1. Specify a success handler for load.

   ```
   $("#main-div").load("http://www.someurl.com/somepage.php", function(){
       $('#item-submit').click(function(){
               jsURL = $('#input').val();
               submit(jsURL);
           });
   });
   ```
2. Use `on` to indicate that the click handler should be assigned to elements that are or will be on the page.

   ```
   $('#item-submit').on('click', function(){
       jsURL = $('#input').val();
       submit(jsURL);
   });
   ```

Answer (score 2):

As all pointed out, the **load** function works asynchronously so, your click handler is not working for the 'future' div.

You can bind handler to a future element like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#item-submit', function(event){
          jsURL = $('#input').val();
          submit(jsURL);  
});
```

This way you can bind your handler in the jQuery document ready function.

Comment: All the responses highlighted the same thing. Thank you too @Shuhel Ahmed.