# How To POST to a PHP file using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

well I have a button when Users Clicks it it got disable and fadeIn a Message Thanks We will take care of this soon 
but now What I want to do is when ever Users Clicks the button it will disable and then it will post to a php file (say: error.php) this error.php will be like this

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $page= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// now update these to sql database ..... and if successfully posted return true 
}
else{
  return false;
}
```

now if jQuery gets True it will fadeIn a div with sucess message 
else it will fade in another div with error / sorry message

the html and JS looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
 $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
  $("#div1").fadeIn(1000); //if success
  $("#div2").fadeIn(1000); //if error
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" style="display:none;">Success</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">Error</div>
<button id="submit">report The Page</button>
</body>
</html>
```

please help 
thnx

Comment: Where is you `<form>`? Also try `<input type="submit">`

Comment: [Submit a form using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Just do an ajax post....like so...

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
$('#submit').attr('disabled',true);
 $.post("example.php", function() {      
    $("#div1").fadeIn(1000); 
  }).fail(function() { 
    $("#div2").fadeIn(1000);});
```

But i dont know where your form is, so i dont know what data youre posting.

Answer (score 0):

To see how to post via jQuery take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

In your case your javascript code will look something like:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    $('#submit').attr('disabled',true);

    $.post('error.php', function(data) {
        if(data.success) {
            $("#div1").fadeIn(1000);
        } else {
            $("#div2").fadeIn(1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Do you need to submit the contents of a form along with this post? If so, change the above javascript to be like:

```
 $.post('error.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
```

This assumes that you have a `<form id="myform">` that you want to submit to error.php.

It also assumes that your PHP script is returning a 'success' attribute using json, something like (modified from your code):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $page= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    // now update these to sql database
    echo json_encode(array("success" => 1));
}
else{
    echo json_encode(array("success" => 1));
}
```

Comment: no there is no form there is just a button for reporting the page the user clicks the button to report the page .... then it will just added to mySQL table so that i can check the page and remove it if there is something wrong there is just a button if user clicks the  button it will just call a post to a php file and disable the button and fade in success or error message

Comment: @SoumeshBanerjee makes sense. Did I answer your question then? I think the above code should get you going on making the post, receiving the response from the server, and fading in the correct message.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can use the .post() function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

This function uses the HTTP POST Request and has a "success" function. The easiest way to use it is propably:

```
$.post('php/error.php', function(data) {
   console.log(data); // In your case "data" should be either "true" or "false"
});
```

You can pass other parameters as well (see docs). To fadeIn the correct div just check for the "data" parameter of the success function.

Hope this answers your question