# using jquery to check form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my html code:

```
<form action="test/test" method="post">
    <button type="submit" id="post-question"></button> 
</form>
```

my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $('#post-question').click(function()
    {
        alert('hello world');   
    });
});
</script>
```

when I submit the form, nothing happens, no alert dialog showing.
What's wrong in my code?

Comment: how are you submitting the form, is it via the button click?

Comment: One reason I could see is, you are not submitting the form using the submit button click but by either pressing enter key or some other operation

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VnqMy/ - there is nothing wrong with this your code. When you're in stuck - isolate the issue, and STOP GUESSING

Comment: show in this [FIDDLE](http://jsbin.com/orUcIC/2/edit) how to implement in the head - jquery & script

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit a form using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

Comment: I find the problem, it's caused by another jquery error. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Use the submit event instead of the click event. Most forms need to be validated on the client side, so clicking the button isn't necessary properly submitting the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#form').submit(function(){
       alert('hello world');   
       e.preventDefault();
   });
</script>

<form action="test/test" method="post" id="form">
    <button type="submit" id="post-question"></button> 
</form>
```

Comment: You may also want to add `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Good piece of advice. Forgot about that

Comment: Hi, I want to check whether the inputs in the form is valid. So I want to check the inputs when the submit button clicks. If the inputs are valid, the form is submitted via ajax. If the inputs are invalid, the submit will be prevented.

Comment: @Charles: do you have any particular question? You're new here - so just so you know, SO is for helping you to develop, not doing your job for you for free.

Answer (score 1):

As zerkms has pointed out, there is [nothing wrong](http://jsfiddle.net/VnqMy) with the codes above. The problem is somewhere else. But anyway you can also use the `.submit()` function:

```
$( "#the-form-id" ).submit(function(event) {
  alert( "yo world" );
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Hi, I want to check whether the inputs in the form is valid. So I want to check the inputs when the submit button clicks. If the inputs are valid, the form is submitted via ajax. If the inputs are invalid, the submit will be prevented.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to validate the for before submission you can try this.

```
    <form action="test/test" method="post" onsubmit="validate">
        <button type="submit" id="post-question"></button> 
    </form>

 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function validate(){
      // do you validation here
     }    
  </script>
```

Comment: In 2013 it's a shame to use `onsubmit`