# I need help building a jQuery form for adding medicine

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to build this form and I have no idea where to begin. What I need is a simple validation form for a medical website. I need users to be able to do the following:

1. Input Medication name, Dosage, and Frequency.
2. Select "Add" button and it adds the information to a list (located to the right of this form)
3. They can add as many medications as they want. When they click submit it will send the information through e-mail.

Is this easy to accomplish? Is there any type of script available open source that can be changed to do this? I'm not too familiar with javascript or jquery but I feel I could figure out how to modify a script if it was close to what I have described.

Comment: This is not a code requesting page. Post some code, what you have tried and we will help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit a form using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I have no idea what on earth would make you think that. If anyone is willing to help me or point me in the right direction that would be great. Otherwise please keep your comments to yourself. I'm not requesting code, I'm requesting help. I don't need someone to write a script for me, but a point in the right direction to find a good starting point would be great.

Comment: @ChrisL -- Start with jQuery selectors and `click()` and `change()` events, should get you going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see these jquery demos, its very helpful:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal