# Sending email by form without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Im creating page with parallax scrolling, contact box is in last section. If I use simple html + php contact box, page will refresh to first section, so user will have to scroll back to contact section to see result. To correct this I am trying to make script that will send email without reloading page. (by Jquery)

This is how it looks like:

HTML:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formularz">
        <label  for="name">Imię</label><input type="text" name="name" id="formularz_name"/></br></br>
        <label  for="email">Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="formularz_email"/></br></br>
        <label  for="phone">Telefon</label><input type="text" name="phone" id="formularz_phone"/></br></br>
        <label  for="enquiry">Zapytanie</label><textarea name="enquiry" cols="20" rows="10" id="formularz_text"></textarea></br></br>
        <input type="submit" id="contact_button" value="Wyślij" />
        </form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#contact_button').click(function () {


    var name = $('#formularz_name').val();
    var email = $('#formularz_email').val();
    var phone = $('#formularz_phone').val();
    var text = $('#formularz_text').val();

          $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/contact.php',
            data: {'name': name, 'email': email, 'phone': phone, 'text': text},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(odp){
                alert(odp);
            }

           });

});
```

PHP:

```
<?php





    if (!$name || !$email || !$phone || !$text) {
        $problem = TRUE;
       echo("<br><p>Musisz wypełnić wszystkie pola.</p>");
    }       

    if (!$problem){


    $data = date("d.m.y");


    $message = "
    <p>Name: $name</p>
    <p>Phone: $phone</p>
    <p>Email: $email</p>
    <br>
    <p>Enquiry: $text</p>";


$od = "$email";
$content = $message;
$header = "From: $od \r\n";
$header  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
 (mail('lethysek@gmail.com', 'New message from website Angelzena', $content, $header));



                     echo("<br><p>Wiadomość została wysłana.</p>");

    }else{
          echo("<p>Spróbuj ponownie</p>");
         }                    



?>
```

Why it doesn't work? When i click submit, page is refreshed and nothing happens.

Comment: The way you are trying to access request variables in your php script is incorrect. It should look like `$_REQUEST['name of the variable']`

Comment: `if (!$name || !$email || !$phone || !$text)` Where come from these variables? Try `$_POST['name']`

Comment: My first impression is that you might have some redundant code. You surround your inputs with a <form> (which I believe forces a refresh) and usually runs a php script. You also have a jQuery ajax request. Try removing the <form> wrapper - your POST should still occur. As the two commenters above mentioned, you also need the $_POST[...]

Comment: You should use .submit(). You can find everything here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery

Comment: Your full page refresh is performed by clicking `<input type="submit" .../>` button, which sends form data to your server using regular HTTP request. You can use another HTML element to trigger AJAX call to your server or prevent form submission using javascript, which is a good solution because of non-JS users. Anyway as it is written above, your PHP code needs a lot of revisions.

Comment: Btw. removing `<form>` element as Kyle Sum commented is a bad solution because of HTML validity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First

Using `button` instead of `submit` to prevent refreshing.

Change `<input type="submit" id="contact_button" value="Wyślij" />`
To `<input type="button" id="contact_button" value="Wyślij" />`

Answer (score 1):

Try to serialize your form data to avoid unnecessary geting input values and prevent the default action of form (submit).

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/contact.php',
        data: formData,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(odp){
            alert(odp);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the  wrapper around the  tags (you already have a jquery ajax() call to POST) and add the $_POST['name'] as others mentioned to actually initialize your php variables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the form from submitting in your jquery. Try this:

```
$('#formularz').submit(function ( e ) {


    var name = $('#formularz_name').val();
    var email = $('#formularz_email').val();
    var phone = $('#formularz_phone').val();
    var text = $('#formularz_text').val();

          $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/contact.php',
            data: {'name': name, 'email': email, 'phone': phone, 'text': text},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(odp){
                alert(odp);
            }

           });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the form tag...its force your page to refresh.it will work for you.