# mvc - give submit buttons same name when using dynamic value

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a list of items in my view and each has the below submit input type. Each input type has a dynamic value that is then passed through to the parameter 'int button' so the controller is aware of which button has been selected.
**View**

```
<input type="submit" name="button" value="@Model.Sites[i].Id" />
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ViewInvoice(List<string> invoice, List<int> site, int button = 0)
{
}
```

The dynamic value is posted correctly to the controller however the buttons are named in the view according to this dynamic value "@Model.Sites[i].Id". How can i set all the button names to "Select" while keeping the dynamic value for my controller?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

try using this:

```
<button type="submit" name="button" value="@Model.Sites[i].Id">Select</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have given it a go and when running locally through visual studio is works perfectly however when released to the server it doesn't seem to be passing through the dynamic value "button" anymore. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

the timing will be a little tricky but you can try this

```
<input type="submit" value="Select" class="btnSubmit1" />
```

then in your script set a hidden field based on the button click

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btnSubmit1').on('click', function(){
        $('.hdnButton').val('btnSubmit1');
    });
});
```

If the form submits before the field is set then you may need to change the button type to button, set the field and submit the form via ajax  [Submit a form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)