# How To Get ASP.NET MVC Form To do same as button submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC Form that has code like the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new
{
  action = "https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll",
  id = "registerformid",

}))
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(a => a.RegisterUserInfoLoggedIn.AttendeesId)
  ...
```

I've got a JQuery ajax call I do and if that JQuery is successful, I want my form to POST to the action url for further processing.

My JQuery looks like the following,but what I can't figure out is what to put in my JQuery ajax success event such that I post back to the action url, that page responds properly and shows me my new page.

```
               success: function (data) {
                    if (donationAmount > 0.00) {
                        $.post("https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll", {
                            x_login: 'xxx',
                            x_amount: 19.99,
                            x_description: 'Sample Transaction',
                            ...

                        }, function(datax) {

                            this.submit();
                        });
```

Comment: Can't you just use `$("#registerformid").submit()` in your success function?

Comment: is this helps? In success event put window.location.href = 'new page url';

Comment: Checkout the top votes answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke your form's submit using `.Submit()`

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#registerformid').submit(); // right here.   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following.

Return proper json format based on your Action status.

```
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        return this.Json(new
        {
            redirectUrl = "/ControllerName/ActionName",
            isRedirect = true
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Redirect to provided page on success method.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: '/Home/SomeAction',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: json,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        // redirect to home if true
        if (data.isRedirect) {
            window.location.href = data.redirectUrl;
        }
    }
});
```