# How submit a form from JQuery function without ID

Tags: php, jquery

I have this form,  but this form inside PHP foreach function that gives the value from database, so I can't give the form id because redundancy will happened. And when click on any star in stars rating it will do as a submit, go to function so in the function I want to submit the form without id how?

```
<form class="watching-us-reating-form" name="swatching-us-reating-form" action=" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="watchlist_id" value="<?php echo $fundAndUserWatchingThem['contactId']?>">
    <!-- This hidden field used to save the value of the rating before submit -->
    <input type="text" name="priority" class="watching-us-reating-value">

    <!-- This DIV to contain the stars rating -->
    <div class="watching-us-rating-div" data-score="<?php echo $flag; ?>" data-number="<?php echo $numberOfStars; ?>"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit a form using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

Comment: @Manibharathi i believe its different since here he  want to submit particular form with require use of other code/function and have certain condition instead just submitting form

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `closest()` to get the `form` element related to the clicked star rating:

```
$('.watching-us-rating-div').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Also, your `form` tag is missing an `action` - is that an error in your example?

Comment: Thank you, about the action i will add it but i has an inquiry! how i will save the data as a value inside the text field from the jquery function? without id because also a redundancy will happened?

Comment: @user3706803 that value will be sent to your server side script to be saved wherever you require.