# jQuery Focus() and automatic Keypress()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for being such a beginner but I spent days try to find an answer and now I think your expertise is needed.

I try to do something like "If I click on li, then the text written in li is displayed in a search box (ID '#input#) and automatically the request is launched."

My script works fine but the request/search IS NOT launched.I blocked at the last step of the process.

Thank you very much for your help.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="test">
  <li>Hello world</li>
  <li>Hello world 2</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript, JQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test li").click(function (){
        varindex = $(this).text();
        $('#input').val("Text is in the search box!"+" "+varindex);
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test li").click(function (){
        $('#input').focus();
        $('#input').trigger(jQuery.Event('key', {which: 13}));
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Is your `input` in a form ?

Comment: can you post your complete html?

Comment: You want to submit the form? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery

Comment: I wrote input Html but did not work. I put it there :  <div id="go">
    <input id="input" type="search" value=""/>
    </div>

Comment: ??? Where is the `<form>` tag?

Comment: No there is no form, just a search box and some jquery behind to display a video.

Comment: *"request/search IS NOT launched."* How are you triggering the request..? all we can say seeing the currently shared code is: "request is not fired since there is no code above to fire a request"

Comment: OK thanks everyone. The code is fine. It's just me who had to change another script by focus() instead of keyup(). Use it if you want it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
   $('#test li').click ( function () {
      $('#input').attr("value", $(this).text ());
      $('#myform').submit ();
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="test">
<li>    Hello world </li>
<li>    Hello world 2   </li>
</ul>
<form id="myform" action="xxx.yyy.zz" method="get">
<input id="input" name="myinput" type="text" />
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: thansk. I did not try this one but still, i think i am not using a form but a search box only, though...