# Best way to handle jQuery/HTML form with questions, sub questions, and forms?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a very large form that's essentially a questionnaire.

It has 19 questions, some of which when answered `Yes` have 1-5 more questions dropdown.

The way I'm doing this now is using jQuery `.change()` and `.hide()`/`.show()`.

If the answer to a question without a sub question is `Yes`, a dropdown with a date, textarea, and file input appears.  If the answer to a question with a sub question or sub questions is `Yes`, 1-5 more questions appear that when answered `Yes` have a dropdown form with a date, textarea, and file input.

What's the best way to handle the markup, JS/jQuery, and ship the data to the backend?

As of now I'm doing something like this, and this ONLY accounts for the yes or no answer:

```
var answers = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= 42; i++) {
    var question = $('#q' + i + '');

    if(question.is(':checked'))
        var answer = 'Yes';
    else
        var answer = 'No';

    answers.push({
        'question': answer
    });
}

var content = {
    'answers': answers
};

$.ajax({
    url: '/questions',
    type: 'POST',
    data: content,
    success: function(result) {
        var result = JSON.stringify(result);
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

I stop the loop at 42 because there are 42 questions.  This gets complicated with the form and their respective class/id names and getting those values and sending the data.

What's the best way to do this to also send many date, text, and file input fields..?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is with a plain old HTML form and a little bit of jQuery to help toggle what is visible/not visible.

Basically, a 'toggle-trigger' class is added to the elements that trigger other content areas. Each toggle-trigger needs to know what toggle area to show/hide, so a data-toggle-area is added to this as well.

An example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".toggle-trigger").change(function(event) {
                $(".toggle-trigger").each(function(index, element) {
                    var $element = $(element);
                    var $toggleArea = $($element.data("toggle-area"));

                    if($element.is(":checked")) {
                        $toggleArea.show();
                    } else {
                        $toggleArea.hide();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/questions" method="post">
        <div>
            This is question one.
            <label>Yes<input class="toggle-trigger" type="radio" name="q1" value="Yes" data-toggle-area="#q1-yes" /></label>
            <label>No<input class="toggle-trigger" type="radio" name="q1" value="No" data-toggle-area="#q1-no"/></label>

            <div id="q1-yes" style="display:none;">
                This is question one subquestion for YES.
                <input type="date" name="q1-date"/>
            </div>
            <div id="q1-no" style="display:none;">
                This is question one subquestion for NO.
                <input type="file" name="q1-file"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think if you are using jQuery to build and post the form, you're probably working too hard. Let the plain old html form do it's thing, and use jquery to just show/hide what parts of the form are accessible.

Comment: How would this work?  Every question is different.  Would it look like this * 40ish?

Comment: Yeah, I would expect you to have multiple pairs of toggle triggers and toggle areas.

Comment: It has to use AJAX because it's part of a wizard.  Prior to answering these questions there's 3 other forms the user filled out.

Comment: And I assume the other 3 forms are already being submitted with jquery? Why not just post each one of those forms, have the server do its thing and move you on to the next step in the wizard?

Comment: It uses a wizard from a theme.  This must use jQuery to send the data or a week's worth of work is wasted.

Comment: Fair enough. To submit the form with jquery, I'd suggest looking at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1200312/3915110). Serialize the form and ship it :)