# Minimal length in textarea validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my script.
It is only partly working. If i enter less then 15 charachters the alert appears but then i click ok on the alert massage and the from gets send anyway. I am not sure waht i'm doing wrong. Here is my script:

```
function checktextarea() {
var minLength = 15;
var $textarea = $('#massage');
if($textarea.text().split(/\s+/).length < minLength) {
  alert('You need to enter at least ' + minLength + ' words');
    return false;
 }
}
```

This is the html:

```
<form action="kontaktsi.php" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" class="contact_form" onsubmit="checktextarea()">
 <span class="sporo">
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" class="contacttextform form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
 </span>
 <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="contacttextform" placeholder="Your email" required><br><br>
 <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="8" rows="8" class="contacttextarea" placeholder="text text text?" required></textarea>
 <br>
 <div class="send">
  <input name="send" type="submit" class="contactformbutton" style="width:150px;" value="Send">
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: how are you calling checktextarea()?

Comment: add your markup also.

Comment: Make sure you use `return checktextarea()`, and not just `checktextarea()` when you call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `<form>` tag into this:

```
<form action="kontaktsi.php" ... method="post" onsubmit="return checktextarea()">
```

You need to add `return` to the call, in order to pass the boolean value `false` to the submit event.

There's also a typo in your script: change `$('#massage')` into `$('#message')`
Finally, you need to use `val()` instead of `text()` to get the value of a `<textarea>`. 
Here's the final script:

```
function checktextarea() {
    var minLength = 15;
    var textarea = $('#message');
    if(textarea.val().replace(' ') < minLength) {
        alert('You need to enter at least ' + minLength + ' words');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did it like u said. But the message get's send. It does show me the alert notice like when i don't use return but the problem is still there, i still get the message on my email.

Comment: @user3337790 there are a few more flaws in your script, check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if it is the only way, but the last time I solved this problem I avoided the generic `onsubmit` mechanism; precisely because of the missing way of breaking in case of error.

Instead, one can bind a jQuery `submit` event and then use `preventDefault()` in case of error, as described here:

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

One can even submit directly with jQuery: [Submit a form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

It is slightly more work, but you have much better control.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
function checktextarea() {
  var minLength = 15;
  var $textarea = $('#massage');
  if($textarea.val().split(' ').length < minLength) {
    alert('You need to enter at least ' + minLength + ' words');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try what? This is a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer.

Comment: He says he gets the alert, so his problem isn't with how he checks the length.

Comment: you see that `$textarea.val().split(' ').length`

Comment: You should explain what you changed in the answer, not expect people to search for it.

Comment: Using `' '` instead of the existing regex is going to make things worse since `foo  bar` will now count as three words instead of two.

Comment: I'm soo sorry, I know now. U use `checktextarea()` function in your submit function so change it with this in your button attribute maybe `onclick="checktextarea();return false;"`

Comment: Consider editing your answer (there is an edit button below) instead of posting a comment.