# PHP Private Chat Long polling integration

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

i've got a simple question here,

Ive got this form thats inside my chat html:

```
<form action="../addchat.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                    <textarea id="textarea" style="border-radius:0px; border:none; background-color:rgb(243,243,243); min-height:100px;"name="comment" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br>
                    <input height="25px" width="20px" style="float:right;" type="image" src="../arrow.png" name="submit" value="Comment">

</form>
```

This form is for users to submit their chat messages. and after which, form post will direct the information to addchat.php, which contains the following code:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include_once("config.php");



$reply=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['comment']);
$cid=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['cid']);
$uid=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['userid']);
$time=time();
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$q= mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO conversation_reply (user_id_fk,reply,ip,time,c_id_fk) VALUES ('$uid','$reply','$ip','$time','$cid')") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 

?>
```

This script obviously adds the data into the tables and after which another script on the chat html page will display out the chat messages.

However, the current issue is that firstly, after user click submit, page will redirect to another blank page and show success message. Secondly, user need to refresh to see the new chat messages.

This chat application is a private chat (similar to Facebook), so not very sure how to do it? Would appreciate some help:)

Comment: I'd recommend NodeJS and SocketIO, here is  basic chat example which will cover the basics and is on topic for your chat program. http://socket.io/demos/chat/

Comment: I did a check on SocketIO and Node, and it seems to me that they are more for group chat applications, whereas in my case i am looking more at a private chat (something like Facebook), would it still work in that case?

Comment: yes it would. you could like.. authenticate users, put them into broadcast groups (chat rooms) or let them talk directly to each other. the main difference between node and php is that in node you always have access to all connections. (you could srsly put the connections into an array and iterate over them to broadcast messages).. anyways.. if you do want to do this in php.. you can increase the amount of time untill php hangs up the connection. just sleep your php script untill there is data available (like requesting for new messages each second from db) and then respond to the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want it to redirect. Move the PHP code to the same file as the form. You could use `include` for this.
Then make the form `action=""`.
Then around the PHP, you need to check that the POST exists so it only runs when the form submits:
e.g.

```
 if (!empty($_POST))
```

As for the refresh problem. You may want to look into AJAX or even [socket.io](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/).

Comment: socket.io requires nodejs though

Comment: Yes it does. But it is just another option to consider.

Answer (score 0):

standard html form submissions always will submit (and redirect) to the page defined in the `action` attribute of the form. with jquery you can prevent this default behavior plus send the form-data with ajax:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "../addchat.php",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: {
            comment: $("#textarea").text()
        },
        success: function(data){
            //something you could do on success of your ajax call.
            //you might not need it in this case.
        }
    });
});
```

secondly, you'll need some procedure that refreshes your output-area automatically. create a div in your html to show the chat-output:

```
<div id="chat_content_div"></div>
```

then you'll have to do something like this in your javascript to refresh it automatically:

```
var refresh_time = 500; // chat refresh time in ms

setInterval(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url: "chat_output.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $("#chat_content_div").html(data);
        }
    });
}, refresh_time);
```

in the "chat_output.php" you only display (html) data from the database to be displayed in this div.

Comment: I will test this out, but one issue as others pointed out is that using a combination of php ajax would overload apache worker threads, so i guess i will stick to node.js after all. THANKS anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It is not simple to answer this question, as it belongs to how hard/complex you want in your chat application.

1. If you don't want to get redirect when submitting, you can use AJAX to post the form [Submit a form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)
2. If you don't want to refresh the page to load new chat messages, you can use AJAX call to get new messages in interval of time http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp.
3. If you want to receive new chat messages at the time they are sent from sender (who is chatting with current user), you might consider about using push server like NodeJS (http://nodejs.org) or Socket.io (http://socket.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use PHP for that purpose if I were you, or if you do, you'll need lot of ajax to make this chat working.

ajax request to send... ajax request every n milliseconds to fetch new messages. you should also use an api instead of a webpage to interact with your server-side app. Your server will need to be highy available and respond really fast.

You should choose a language that support [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) (take a look at [python](https://www.python.org/) with [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), for example, or java, or whatever...) if you want this chat to be really efficient.

While writing these lines I found something ([Ratchet library](http://socketo.me/))to use websocket in php (I don't know how it works but maybe you'll get problems with the max_execution_time of your server if it works with a "while true" loop)

Edit: as Tuan Duong suggests, nodejs is another good alternative

Comment: well for a small private chat for private purposes some simple ajax-chat is enough, imho. websockets are really hard to use, specially if you are completely new to web-programming. depends if he wants to do it by himself and learn something, or if he just wants a working chat of course.

Comment: I think he wants to learn, if not, there's plenty of ready-to-use php chat tools

Comment: haha thanks guys, I'm a beginner in javascript/ajax/jquery, i did have a look at Node.Js, the only worry is whether i would be able to integrate it with my current php (that might be an issue)

Comment: If you're a beginner then make a bridge beetween the 2 languages might be a bit tricky. Maybe you could/should try ajax requests between your page and the server. But a live chat even using this method is a bit tricky for a beginner, maybe you could use a ready-to-use php chat library like [phpfreechat](https://github.com/kerphi/phpfreechat) or [Blab!](http://hot-things.net/)