# form submit always return true while it should return false

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I'm validating a form before submitting using this code

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return reg()">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="off" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone</td>
<td><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" autocomplete="off" placeholder="001**********"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="register"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and this js code

```
function reg(){
    var user = $("#username").val(),
        pass = $("#password").val(),
        city = $("#city").val(),
        email = $("#email").val(),
        phone = $("#phone").val();

    if(user.length<4){
        alert('short name');
        return false;
    }
    else if(pass.length<6) {
        alert('password error');
        return false;
    }
    else if(city.length<3) {
        alert('city error');
        return false;
    }
    else if(phone.length<6) {
        alert('phone error');
        return false;
    }
    else{
        $.post('ajax/checkex.php?user='+user+"&email="+email).done(function (data) {
            if(data.indexOf('user') !== -1){
                alert('user name is not available');
                return false;
            }
            else if(data.indexOf('email') !== -1){
                alert('email address is already registered');
                return false;
            }
            else if(data.indexOf('available') !== -1){
                return true;
            }
        });
      //return false;
    }
}
```

But the form always submits and the ajax code does not work at all. It does not  even alert anything inside like `alert(data)`.

The js code returns true even though the name and the email are already registered before.

When I uncomment the last `return false` line it returns false and the ajax works fine but sure the form does not submit at all. So where's the error in this code?

Comment: ajax is asynchronous and even if it wasn't returning boolean from inside a callback won't return anyhting to  `reg()`. Suggest you read up on remote ajax validation

Comment: The issue seems to be with the Asynchronous nature of Ajax.  The .done function is called after returning.

Comment: The return is inside .done and if there's no return false after it, it won't work so how to check if user or email are not registered and return false or true using Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will always post the form. If you want to submit the form with jquery, you can use the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event.

You can use the event.preventDefault method to prevent a form from submitting.

A simple example

```
$("myForm").submit(function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   //Check if the inputs are valid
   if( formvalid ){
      $.ajax() //Make your ajax call 
   }
})
```

Also see : [Submit a form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

Edit : This shouldn't submit if your ajax call returns false

```
$("myForm").submit(function(ev){
  $.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "post",
    async: false, //To make the ajax call synchronous
    success: function(valid){
      if(!valid)
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
  }); 
})
```

Comment: $("#regForm").submit(function (e) { e.preventDefault();
validation here
ajaxe here
if ajax returns true: $("#regForm").submit();
the ajax works but the form does not submit because the default action has been prevented

Comment: Isn't your purpose to prevent the form from submitting and submit the data via an ajax call? That is what I understood. If you want to use the ajax call just for validation you can make a synchronous ajax call and call ev.preventDefault only when it returns false.

Comment: The purpose is checking availability of user name and email address then submit the form normally

Comment: Try the edit in that case. I have not ran a test with it but it should work seeing that your main problem previously was the asynchronous nature of the ajax call, making it synchronous should solve it. However, this is not an elegant solution I would recommend. There are much better ways to validate a form.