# Saving the output of a form to a text file via jQuery/Javascript posting to a php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've got a simple html form that as you can see below has been pre-filled with information for example purposes.

[image: Example form]

Currently when you click submit the form will be saved to Google Docs which works perfectly.

**However** I also want it to *log/save* the form output to a text file on the server where the page will be hosted.

#### Example Pre-Filled Form: http://jsfiddle.net/owcnwfhp/

The format I am wanting it to be logged/saved as is shown below, each new line is a new form submission.

#### Example Expected Output:

```
3/18/2015 8:06:27   testname    test4   test2   test3   test4   test5   test6   test7   test8   test9   test10
3/18/2015 8:07:07   testname1   test4   test4   test3   test4   test5   test6   test7   test8   test9   test10
3/18/2015 8:08:01   testname2   test2   test2   test3   test4   test5   test6   test7   test8   test9   test10
3/18/2015 8:09:41   testname3   test2   test5   test3   test4   test1   test6   test7   test8   test9   test10
```

**The separating character must be an *ASCII tab character***

I need to be able to make the logging/saving **queue** itself so that if two people used the form at once that there isn't a conflict and only one of the form submissions gets logged/saved.

***I think*** the best location for the capturing/logging/saving of the form would be at the start of the function below that fires once the form has been submitted to Google docs.

```
function breakRedirect() {
    $('#container').replaceWith('<div id="complete">Completed</div>');
};
```

## Function so far...

This is what I have so far, it's in the right format (sure the javascript/jquery might be a bit wrong but it works), I now need to find a way to be able to **post it to a php script?** So that It queues and writes to a file...

```
function breakRedirect() {

    var month = new Array();
        month[0] = "01"; month[1] = "02"; month[2] = "03"; month[3] = "04"; month[4] = "05"; month[5] = "06"; month[6] = "07"; month[7] = "08"; month[8] = "09"; month[9] = "10"; month[10] = "11"; month[11] = "12";
    var collection = new Date().getDate() + "/" + month[new Date().getMonth()] + "/" + new Date().getFullYear() + " "+ new Date().getHours() + ":" + new Date().getMinutes() + ":" + new Date().getSeconds();

    var $inputs = $("input")
    $inputs.each(function () {
        var value = this.value;
        if (value != "Submit Selections" && value != "Clear Selections") {
            collection += "\t" + value
        };
    });

    var $selects = $("select")
    $selects.each(function () {
        var value = this.value;
        collection += "\t" + value
    });

    console.log(collection);

    $('#container').replaceWith('<div id="complete">Completed</div>');
};
```

## Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/owcnwfhp/1/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### jQuery

**$.ajax()**

---

You can do a post using the jQuery.ajax function. See the example below.

```
$.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });
```

For the data attribute you can use:

```
data: $('form#myForm').serialize(),
```

Source: [jQuery website - .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), [Stackoverflow - Submit a form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

### PHP

**file_get_contents() AND $_POST[]**

---

Then you can get the values in your PHP file with the $_POST variable and write it to a file.

**Get the values**

```
// WARNING! You should do some valiadation before writing to the file!
<?php
   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $location = $_POST["location"];
   $new_line = $name . "your tab ascii code" . $location . "\n";
   $file = 'people.txt';

   // Open the file to get existing content
      $current = file_get_contents($file);

   // Append a new person to the file
      $current .= $new_line;

   // Write the contents back to the file
      file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Source: [PHP Website - File put contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: But doesn't that require it's own form... remember I am submitting one post to google docs, I want a secondary post so that I can save the data on my server.

Comment: No. You can use the same form. First submit the form using AJAX. Than your page will not be reloaded. And after that send your form as usual. You can use jquery.submit() for that.

Comment: Then surely I might aswell just do: `data: { data: collection }` as I've already mad the string... it doesn't have to be that accurate just decent enough to log.

Comment: O. Sorry. You are right indeed! You can do: data: {data: collection} -> As long as your string doesn't break the JSON format...