# page redirect back after form submit in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was trying to add the two operator using javascript and then I wished to try it in ajax then I wanted to see the difference between two codes action but whenever I implemented the addition in javascript I got stuck because thepage show the result for a sec then it redirect back. Can anyone please tell me what is the wrong with this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>ajax</title>
    <script>
        function loadFunction(){
            //window.alert("hello");
            var x= document.getElementById("d1");
            var y =document.forms["myForm"]["op1"].value;
            var z =document.forms["myForm"]["op2"].value;
            x.innerHTML="<h2>" +(parseInt(y)+parseInt(z)) + "</h2>";
            x.style.width="35%";
            x.style.border="1px solid #050";    
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="loadFunction()" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="op1" placeholder="operator 1" required></input> + 
        <input type="text" id="op2" placeholder="operator 2" required></input>
        <button type="submit">show the result</button>
    </form>
    <div id="d1">
        <h2>The summation will print here!!!</h2>
    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit a form using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

Comment: Try adding `return false;` at the end of `loadFunction()` to prevent the form from posting.

Comment: nope i was trying it in javascript and i need to test the ajax in javascript@Cymen

Comment: can you explain the reason please ? @Sharlike

Comment: i have tried adding `return false;` at the end of the `loadFunction()` but it didnt do anything@Sharlike

Comment: Take a look at @Tomek's answer. Your form submit is reloading the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The default action** that browser performs each time you submit the form is to make those redirections. You have to explicitly turn this off. To do that add a `event.preventDefault()`, like this:

```
<script>
    function loadFunction(event){
        //window.alert("hello");
        var x= document.getElementById("d1");
        var y =document.forms["myForm"]["op1"].value;
        var z =document.forms["myForm"]["op2"].value;
        x.innerHTML="<h2>" +(parseInt(y)+parseInt(z)) + "</h2>";
        x.style.width="35%";
        x.style.border="1px solid #050";

        event.preventDefault();    
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You have to add `event` also to where you attach the function to your form here: `<form id="myForm" onsubmit="loadFunction(event)" method="POST">`. Here's a working demo: http://jsbin.com/picalu/edit?html,output

Comment: yes its working now ..thanks for the help.@Tomek Sułkowski ..i need to know one more thing .if its reloading the page or not?

Comment: No, it's not. If you prevent the default action, the only thing that's happening is what you have in your `loadFunction` function.

Comment: can you please show an example between non ajax javascript and ajax javascript?@Tomek Sułkowski

Comment: To understand better what AJAX is and how to use it try one of those tutorials: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started or http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

The other possibility is to `return false` in onsubmit like that:

```
<script>
    function loadFunction(){
        //...
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

and

```
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="return loadFunction()" method="POST">
```

You can then control if form should be submitted by returning either `true` or `false` from `loadFunction()`.