# return true after jQuery validation wont submit my form

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form that I am validating with jQuery, once validation is passed I want to submit the form:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[name="form"]').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var one = $('[name="one"]');
            var two = $('[name="two"]');
            var three = $('[name="three"]');
            var errors = [];

            if(!one.val()){
                errors.push(one);
            }
            if(!two.val()){
                errors.push(two);
            }
            if(!three.val()){
                errors.push(three);
            }

            if(errors.length > 0){
                $.each(errors, function(i, v){
                    $(v).css('border', '1px solid red');
                });
            } else {
                console.log('true');
                $('#bmi-form').submit();
            }
        });
    });
```

My idea was that the return true at the end would submit the form but it does nothing..

In the console I see the console.log('true');

So how can I submit the form on validation success... I dont want to use any plugins as it is a very small app and there is no need to bloat it.

Regards

Comment: `$('form#myForm').submit();`?

Comment: because you already use prevent default. try to submit form with id of form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `e.preventDefault();` which stops the form to get submitted. Now you can `.submit()` the form instead of `return true;`:

```
} else {
    console.log('true');
    this.submit(); // return true;
}
```

or remove the `e.preventDefault()` and change to this code to submit only when there are no errors:

```
if(errors.length > 0){
    $.each(errors, function(i, v){
        $(v).css('border', '1px solid red');
    });
    e.preventDefault(); // put e.preventDefault(); stop to submit incase of errors
} else {
    console.log('true');
    // just remove the return true; from here because if everything is 
}   // fine form will submit. Or you can just remove the else block.
```

Comment: I did try this but I get console.log('true') 1400 times in the console and the form still doesnt submit...

Answer (score 0):

User $("form").submit(); if your data is in form or of dynamically validation is created then do ajax call; 
References

[API](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)

[submit-a-form-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit your form...

`$("formid").submit();`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('[name="form"]').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var one = $('[name="one"]');
            var two = $('[name="two"]');
            var three = $('[name="three"]');
            var errors = [];

            if(!one.val()){
                errors.push(one);
            }
            if(!two.val()){
                errors.push(two);
            }
            if(!three.val()){
                errors.push(three);
            }

            if(errors.length > 0){
                $.each(errors, function(i, v){
                    $(v).css('border', '1px solid red');
                });
            } else {
                console.log('true');
                $("formid").submit();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: after some debugging it seems that the $('formid').submit(); is looping the code above and resubmitting the form loads of times..