# PHP Redirect after login

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

Im new at PHP. Can you help me with redirect after login?

After login redirect goes to */user_menu.php*. I want the same: if i login from page */browse.php?id=198* (it is the category link), after login i redirect to the same page, not to user_menu.php.

Sorry for dublicate question. Im just want to share with you my code. Thanks for helping :)

Login form

```
<form class="form"  name="login" action="{SSLURL}user_login.php" method="post" id="login-nav">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">{L_003}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="{L_003}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">{L_004}</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="{L_004}">
        <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="{SITEURL}forgotpasswd.php">{L_215}</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="action" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">{L_275}</button>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input for="rememberme" type="checkbox"> {L_25_0085}
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Full user_login.php code

```
<?php

include 'common.php';

$NOW = time();

if ($system->SETTINGS['https'] == 'y' && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on')
{
    $sslurl = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $system->SETTINGS['siteurl']);
    $sslurl = (!empty($system->SETTINGS['https_url'])) ? $system->SETTINGS['https_url'] : $sslurl;
    header('location: ' . $sslurl . 'user_login.php');
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
{
    $password = md5($MD5_PREFIX . $_POST['password']);
    $query = "SELECT id, hash, suspended FROM " . $DBPrefix . "users WHERE
            nick = '" . $system->cleanvars($_POST['username']) . "'
            AND password = '" . $password . "'";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $system->check_mysql($res, $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
    {
        // generate a random unguessable token
        $_SESSION['csrftoken'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
        $user_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
        if ($user_data['suspended'] == 9)
        {
            $_SESSION['signup_id'] = $user_data['id'];
            header('location: pay.php?a=3');
            exit;
        }

        if ($user_data['suspended'] == 1)
        {
            $ERR = $ERR_618;
        }
        elseif ($user_data['suspended'] == 8)
        {
            $ERR = $ERR_620;
        }
        elseif ($user_data['suspended'] == 10)
        {
            $ERR = $ERR_621;
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['WEBID_LOGGED_IN']        = $user_data['id'];
            $_SESSION['WEBID_LOGGED_NUMBER']    = strspn($password, $user_data['hash']);
            $_SESSION['WEBID_LOGGED_PASS']      = $password;
            // Update "last login" fields in users table
            $query = "UPDATE " . $DBPrefix . "users SET lastlogin = '" . gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "' WHERE id = " . $user_data['id'];
            $system->check_mysql(mysql_query($query), $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
            // Remember me option
            if (isset($_POST['rememberme']))
            {
                $remember_key = md5(time());
                $query = "INSERT INTO " . $DBPrefix . "rememberme VALUES (" . $user_data['id'] . ", '" . $remember_key . "')";
                $system->check_mysql(mysql_query($query), $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
                setcookie('WEBID_RM_ID', $remember_key, time() + (3600 * 24 * 365));
            }
            $query = "SELECT id FROM " . $DBPrefix . "usersips WHERE USER = " . $user_data['id'] . " AND ip = '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "'";
            $res = mysql_query($query);
            $system->check_mysql($res, $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
            if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 0)
            {
                $query = "INSERT INTO " . $DBPrefix . "usersips VALUES
                        (NULL, '" . $user_data['id'] . "', '" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "', 'after','accept')";
                $system->check_mysql(mysql_query($query), $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
            }

            // delete your old session
            if (isset($_COOKIE['WEBID_ONLINE']))
            {
                $query = "DELETE from " . $DBPrefix . "online WHERE SESSION = '" . strip_non_an_chars($_COOKIE['WEBID_ONLINE']) . "'";
                $system->check_mysql(mysql_query($query), $query, __LINE__, __FILE__);
            }

            if (in_array($user_data['suspended'], array(5, 6, 7)))
            {
                header('location: message.php');
                exit;
            }

            if (isset($_SESSION['REDIRECT_AFTER_LOGIN']))
            {
                $URL = str_replace('\r', '', str_replace('\n', '', $_SESSION['REDIRECT_AFTER_LOGIN']));
                unset($_SESSION['REDIRECT_AFTER_LOGIN']);
            }
            else
            {
                $URL = 'user_menu.php';
            }

            header('location: ' . $URL);
            exit;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $ERR = $ERR_038;
    }
}

$template->assign_vars(array(
        'ERROR' => (isset($ERR)) ? $ERR : '',
        'USER' => (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : ''
        ));

include 'header.php';
$template->set_filenames(array(
        'body' => 'user_login.tpl'
        ));
$template->display('body');
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: You could see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php, specifically read under 'HTTP_REFERER'.

Comment: You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure) and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: you can add referred url in session and access it after login to redirect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to another page right after login, just use a redirect:

```
header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/whatever-page.php'); exit();
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I got it wrongly. You want to go back to whatever page you logged in from, right?

I would suggest to set a cookie on click. If you're using jquery, when user submit the login form you can save a cookie with the current url.

Then after login, read that cookie with php and redirect the user (or you could also redirect using jquery).

Have a look at this code for more information:

```
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery
```

Comment: Sorry, but its hard for me to do this. I'll read, but im not good in php and jq :(

Comment: I understand but it's easier than what you think, and you should learn some jquery if youre doing front end development too.

Comment: You could also use only php by adding a hidden field in your login form with the current url and then after submit, you could redirect to it.

Comment: Thanks, but can you help me? I tried this: 
`<?php
session_start(); // starts the session
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // i.e. "about.php"
This utilizes the $_SERVER variables to return the URI of the current page visited using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

`<?php
session_start();  // needed for sessions.
if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) 
   $url = $_SESSION['url']; // holds url for last page visited.
else 
   $url = "index.php"; // default page for 

header("Location: http://example.com/$url"); // perform correct redirect.
'` Bud it didnt helped me