# Submit dropdown form upon changing selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

So I have a dropdown menu with 'Next' and 'Prev' (previous) buttons. I would like it so upon pressing next or prev it would also submit the dropdown choice.

```
<input type="button" id="change2" value="prev" />
<select id="Questions">
  <option value="QA">QUESTION A</option>
  <option value="QB">QUESTION B</option>
  <option value="QC">QUESTION C</option>
  <option value="QD">QUESTION D</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="change" value="next" />
```

And here is the JQuery for it:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var dd = $('#Questions'),
        max_len = dd.find('option').length;

    $('#change').click(function () {
        var x = dd.find('option:selected').index();
        if (max_len == x + 1) {
            x = -1;
        }
        dd.find('option').eq(x + 1).prop('selected', true);
    });
    $('#change2').click(function () {
        var x = dd.find('option:selected').index();
            if (max_len == x + 1) {
                x = -1;
            }
        dd.find('option').eq(x - 1).prop('selected', true);
    })
});
```

How can I make it so that when I click next or prev it submits the form too?

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate? (e.g. include the surrounding `<form>`) Is this the only input you want to submit? Where do you want to send the information?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, there is a form around it and this is all I want to submit.

Comment: The information will be processed via cgi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can submit the form using jQuery. Check the top answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery) for details. Assuming you have an `action` attribute set on the form, something like this might be all you need:

```
$('#change').click(function () {
    // your other logic here
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`$.ajax();`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

A very general solution might look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#change, #change2").on('change', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'sendTheDataHere',
            type: 'POST',
            data:  {keyname:$('#Questions option:selected').val()},
            success: function () {},
            error: function () {}
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" id="change2" value="prev" onclick="changeS()"/>
<select id="Questions">
  <option value="QA">QUESTION A</option>
  <option value="QB">QUESTION B</option>
  <option value="QC">QUESTION C</option>
  <option value="QD">QUESTION D</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="change" value="next" onclick="changeS()"/>
```

JS Code

```
<script>
function changeS() {
/* document.getElementById('change').getElementsByTagName('option')[1].selected = true;*/
var r=document.getElementById('change').selectedIndex+1;
document.getElementById('change').getElementsByTagName('option')[r].selected = true;
}
</script>
```