# PHP contact form with post function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my javascirpt code

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you</p>').delay(6000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

I am not getting the field values post function is unable to fetch it

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the method to be "POST" and data in $.ajax, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    data: form.serialize(),
    etc...
```

Also, it would help to see your PHP file.

Comment: it is  not working i tried still i get the mail with no field values

Comment: @VasuSengunthar Can you show us your PHP file and the form?

Comment: open the above link you will get my all html,php,javascript code

Comment: still getting an empty mail

Comment: can someone help me in this

Comment: @VasuSengunthar What results are you getting? Is the PHP file called?

Comment: if i dont use the data: form.serialize(), then the php file is called and i get a empty mail without the field values

Comment: can you help me please

Comment: can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="contact-form wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="600ms">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
            <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" required="required">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required="required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Enter your message" required="required"></textarea>
            </div>                        
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Send Now</button>
            </div>
          </form>   
        </div>
```

This is my html code

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're just sending an empty ajax request.
You will need a **method** and the form **data** to send, for example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json', // <-- not sure if about this
    data: form.serialize(),
beforeSend: function(){
    ...
```

Also see [Submit a form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)