# Javascript how to submit a form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have an issue where I wanted to submit by form with javascript but obviously I have hit an issue when trying to do this and wondered if anyone could help me with the issue, more information can be found below on the issue and the code samples.

Hello. My form .submit function isn't calling when I submit my form that's added, can anyone help?

So first, the form is inside the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editPositionModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:460px;">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content" id="edit-position-content">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the form has yet to be added, so I add it using a function:

```
function modifyPosition(businessId, positionId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxCallUrl + 'api/ajax/positions/' + positionId + '/get-edit-content',
        type: "GET",
        error: function(req, message) {
            showErrorNotification('It seems something went wrong, sorry...');
        },
        statusCode: {
            400: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification(response.responseText);
            },
            500: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification(response.responseText);
            }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            lastModifiedPositionId = positionId;

            $('#edit-position-content').html(data);
            $('#editPositionModal').modal('show');
        },
    });
}
```

I call the above function on the button I click to open the modal with the form on.

Heres the modal content gotten by the ajax request:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Creating a new position</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form id="save_edit_position" method="POST">
    <label>Position Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:20px;" value="{{ $position->position_title }}">
    <label>Position Pay</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="margin-bottom:20px;" value="{{ $position->position_shift_wage }}">
    <label>Position Type</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="business_position_type" id="position_type_modify">
        <option value="employee">Employee</option>
        <option value="supervisor">Supervisor</option>
        <option value="manager">Manager</option>
        <option value="ownership">Ownership</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> &nbsp;Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
var element = document.getElementById('position_type_modify');
element.value = '{{ $position->position_type }}';
</script>
```

And here is the javascript handler for the form submit, on the end of the page where the modal content is included on:

```
$("#save_edit_position").submit(function(e) {
    alert('Submit Called...');
    e.preventDefault(); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxCallUrl + 'api/ajax/positions/' + lastModifiedPositionId + '/save-position',
        data: $("#save_edit_position").serialize(),
        error: function(req, message) {
            showErrorNotification('It seems something went wrong, sorry...' + message);
        },
        statusCode: {
            400: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification(response.responseText);
            },
            500: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification(response.responseText);
            }
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            var mymodal = $('#editPositionModal');
            mymodal.modal('hide');
            showNotification(data, updatePositionsTable(pageBusinessId)); // show response from the php script.
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit a form using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

Comment: Do `ajaxCallUrl ` & `lastModifiedPositionId` have right values?

Comment: If I understood your question, here is the answer: document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a onSubmit="" function handler
`onsubmit="functionhere();"`

Answer (score 3):

Delegate you submit event, your form is dynamically added to the page so you need event delegation to bind your event

```
$('body').on('submit',"#save_edit_position",function(e) {
....
```

or use a delegated click event

```
$('body').on('click',"#save_edit_position input[type='submit']",function(e) {
    ....
```

Note if you have multiple forms on the page with the same id then only the first form with the id will work **ids must be unique**

Comment: This doesn't work, I still get nothing from my submit button.

Comment: @JoshHallow This is not about copy and pasting the code, This is about debugging and retrying. No one is going to work for you.

Comment: is your page refreshing, if its not can you post a picture of your xhr request?

Comment: It's not refreshing, nor do i have any xhr requests relating to this.

Comment: @JoshHallow then your submit event isn't triggering, try to use a click event on the submit button

Answer (score 0):

Your form is incorrectly structured

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> &nbsp;Save</button>
    </form>
```

You cannot, legitimately, straddle the form tag like this and from previous experience this will likely cause problems.

Comment: I've already tried it inside the same `div` tag, I have also had other forms work perfectly fine in different <div tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change your submit type to button like that and add an `onclick` event to a javascript function. If though your form generate dynamically, but I think this should work.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Save" onclick="_submitForm();"/>
</div>
```

And your js should be

```
function _submitForm(){
    alert('Submit Called...');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxCallUrl + 'api/ajax/positions/' + lastModifiedPositionId + '/save-position',
        data: $("#save_edit_position").serialize(),
        error: function(req, message) {
            showErrorNotification('It seems something went wrong, sorry...' + message);
        },
        statusCode: {
            400: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification(response.responseText);
            },
            500: function (response) {
                showErrorNotification(response.responseText);
            }
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            var mymodal = $('#editPositionModal');
            mymodal.modal('hide');
            showNotification(data, updatePositionsTable(pageBusinessId)); // show response from the php script.
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("form.save_edit_position").submit(function(e) {...}
```

I have one more doubt, Can you please share exact location of javascript handler for the form submit in code!!