# javascript form submit redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have my lending page and need some help with form
so i have 2 products in one form

```html
> <form action="x.html" method="post" id="lead-form" validate>
    <select class="form-control" name="requested_product" id="sa">
                                        <option id="x" value="x.html" selected="selected">product x</option>
                                        <option id="y" value="y.html">product y</option>
                                    </select>
<input class="form-control" id="sz" name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" tabindex="2" required="email">
<input class="form-control" id="sf" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="First Name" required>
<input class="form-control" id="sl" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" required>
<button requird="email" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-form">Get Started</button>
</form>
```

so how i do redirect for page of product X when i choose it and submit it or do redirect to page of product Y when i choose it and submit

Comment: Normally you can't submit to a `.html` file and need to submit to a path that will run a server side script to process the data and manage the redirect

Comment: how i do it ? that what i want to know

Comment: Need to study some form processing tutorials specific to whatever server side programming language you have available. `.html` files are typically static resources and have no programming ability

Comment: in javascript possible to do that ? maybe you have an example ?

Comment: This is something you need to research yourself...how web forms work

Comment: but you know answer to my question ?

Comment: There is no simple answer. It requires a full tutorial on how web forms work and is far too broad for one answer

Comment: maybe you have link to tutorial ?

Comment: onchange="this.form.action=this.value  <===== this is a simple answer !!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have some options to solve this.

You need to decide if you want to solve the routing in frontend or backend.

If you do it in frontend you can always use javascript to change the form action attribute when the selection changes.

You could also have a richer application to handle the request submit with ajax instead of the pure native form, if you are new to this you could use jQuery as starter kit.

Take a look to this post about submit form with jQuery:
[Submit a form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

If you want to solve this in the backend, the form will always submit to the same url, then in the backend app you read the selected item and decide to which one redirect the response.

Example in PHP: [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

I hope this helps you

Comment: You should start to read about js and forms. I.E:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation