# To submit a form without redirecting to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, forms

I have been trying to make an online HTML form, which could submit the form and post the data to the local database. However, I don't want the page to be redirected to  `/formfill` URL and send the data to DB without redirecting the page. I have been trying a lot. However, no luck.
Here is my backend node.js code:

```
// require('./../config.js');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var {
    mongoose
} = require('./models/mongoose.js');
var {
    Data
} = require('./models/form.js');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')));

app.post('/formfill', function (req, res) {

    var data = new Data({
        name: req.body.name,
        mailId: req.body.mailId
    })

    data.save().then((doc) => {
        res.status(200).send(doc);
    }).catch((e)=>{
        res.status(400).send(e);
    })
})


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is up");
});
```

Here is my Html form:

```
<form action="/formfill" method="POST" , enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <input class="formfill" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
  <br>
  <input class="formfill" type="text" name="mailId" placeholder="Your email">
  <br>
  <input id="submit-button" class="formfill sumbit-button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And here is my JavaScript code, tried with AJAX too:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#submit-button").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/formfill" method="POST" , enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <input class="formfill" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
  <br>
  <input class="formfill" type="text" name="mailId" placeholder="Your email">
  <br>
  <input id="submit-button" class="formfill sumbit-button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

With AJAX:-

```js
$(function() {
  $("#submit-button").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this));
    $.ajax({
      url: '/formfill',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/formfill" method="POST" , enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
  <input class="formfill" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
  <br>
  <input class="formfill" type="text" name="mailId" placeholder="Your email">
  <br>
  <input id="submit-button" class="formfill sumbit-button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

All I want to do is submit the form without being redirected to `/formfill` or refreshing the page.

Comment: Short answer: do an AJAX request.

Comment: Yes, i have been tying to do that, its being said on every post like this to perform ajax. But its not working, its still being redirected to the '/formfill' with data of the form displayed in json

Comment: If the consensus is to use AJAX and it's not working, then why haven't you included it in _this_ question? We're here to help you help yourself!

Comment: Yes, my mistake, editing the post.

Comment: The `submit` handler should be on the form, not the submit button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit a form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

Comment: @Barmar trying your advice

Comment: @nbrooks, i stumbled upon that one, however , i was using node and wasn't very sure that it only require frontend

Comment: @AlpitAnand in that example provided by nbrooks, the backend (server-side) is irrelevant. You submit the form using Ajax which causes a HTTP request. All server-side languages understand a HTTP request. All you have to do is make sure the request is correct.

Comment: @AlpitAnand Submitting the form is front-end js code only, and the only dependency for that linked post is jQuery. Should work just fine for you!

Comment: Yes, i am going to read each and every link provided by you all. Hoping it would shed some light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `$("#submit-button").submit(function(e) {` with `$("#submit-button").closest("form").submit(function(e) {` :-)

The `preventDefault` method seems to work :

```js
function customSubmit () {
  $("#on-btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $("#off-btn").removeAttr("disabled");
  $("form").on("submit", function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).serialize());
  });
}
function defaultSubmit () {
  $("#off-btn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
  $("#on-btn").removeAttr("disabled");
  $("form").off("submit");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <button id="on-btn" type="button" onclick="customSubmit()">Custom submit</button>
  <button id="off-btn" type="button" onclick="defaultSubmit()" disabled>Default submit</button>
</p>
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="dummy" value="dummy">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

async should be true and other details ,,,

```
     $(function() {
        $("form").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData($(this));
            $.ajax({
                url: '/formfill',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        })
    });
```

here is my test code on localhost,that works fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>d</title>
    <style></style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:800/github/test/formfill.txt" method="POST" , enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <input class="formfill" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name">
        <br>
        <input class="formfill" type="text" name="mailId" placeholder="Your email">
        <br>
        <input id="submit-button" class="formfill sumbit-button" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("form").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData($(this));
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:800/github/test/formfill.txt',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        })
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @AlpitAnand "not working" means what? Any errors in your browser console. This looks like it should be fine.

Comment: jquery-3.2.1.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: I am looking into it, its my console log

Comment: Still being redirected to form fill. :-(

Comment: @AlpitAnand "jquery-3.2.1.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)", there is a problem that has no relation with submitting a form, probably an improper use of HTTP, copy paste the URL into the address bar then debug.

Comment: @leaf, it was displaying when I was using click instead of submit

Comment: A hack would be to **res.redirect('/')** but i found it to be real bad one

Comment: @AlpitAnand Are you able to share the URL of the real app ? We have not enough visibility currently.

Comment: its not being hosted on any server now, its on my local pc only, i can however can give you access to it through TeamViewer or upload the file on git and give you the link

Comment: @AlpitAnand how about testing my test code on your browser?

Comment: @AlpitAnand Do you have a running local server that points to the app folder ?

Comment: Yes , i do, have a local server running

Comment: @AlpitAnand Ok, go for Github then.

Comment: @AlpitAnand How do you start the server ? I'm not familiar with Nodejs :-P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164457/discussion-between-leaf-and-alpit-anand).

Answer (score 0):

Your BE is good but you will need to update the client code.

You should use **Ajax** to accomplish this task.
Ajax will send an HTTP request via the **web API** and won't trigger the browsers redirect action (which submit and anchor tag triggers).
And I see you are using jQuery so you have see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ or https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/.

The thing is that you will need to get the form data manually (via javascript). You can use jQuery as well https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/.

jQuery docmintation is really good. you should give it a look.

Hope this will help you solve your issue.