# How to prevent close of a bootstrap modal after submitting the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using a Bootstrap modal window for a form. I need to prevent the modal from closing after pressing the submit button. I need to close the modal only after clicking the close button. Please help me.

```
  <!--Login, Signup, Forgot Password Modal -->
    <div id="login-signup-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

    <!-- login modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content" id="login-modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Login Now!</h4>
  </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
      <form method="post" id="Login-Form" role="form">

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
            <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter Email" required data-parsley-type="email" >
            </div>                      
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
            <input name="password" id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter Password" required data-parsley-length="[6, 10]" data-parsley-trigger="keyup">
            </div>                      
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked>Remember me</label>
        </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">LOGIN</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <p>
      <a id="FPModal" href="javascript:void(0)">Forgot Password?</a> | 
      <a id="signupModal" href="javascript:void(0)">Register Here!</a>
      </p>
    </div>

   </div>
```

Comment: How is this php-related? Also, I think you might need to post your javscript

Comment: Please change <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">LOGIN</button> to <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg">LOGIN</button>. Then do the needful using JavaScript

Comment: @estinsunny `button type="button"` sounds redundant

Comment: i am using php to submit the form

Comment: To prevent any Clint side actions, must use JavaScript

Comment: @vishnureji PHP should refresh a page while doing submit. So to avoid this you should use javascript/jquery to submit page. Then only modal will be open until you close..

Comment: now when i am clicking the sumbit button the modal window is closing, I need to prevent the closing after the submit button

Comment: how can i use javascript to submit the form ?

Comment: @vishnureji refer this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to see if you can prevent the dialog from submit

```
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) { 
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

And then close it using close button.

Comment: I need to prevent the closing of modal

Comment: Vishnu, when you click on the form button with type 'submit' , page will submit to the action/refresh. This action will automatically close your model window. To avoid this you have to use type as 'button' or you can use onlick event to prevent this. < https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery >

Comment: Please check now my answer, I believe it will solve your problem.

Comment: Try to submit your form using Ajax