# Form POST Requests Body is Empty - Node.js / express / ejs / body-parser

Tags: node.js, forms, express, ejs, body-parser

I'm having trouble with my post from a registration form in node.js. Every time the form is posted the body the request has information but the body is empty. I'm new to node and express so it's probably something small but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Here is my form in ejs:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/users/register">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Re-enter Password">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-dark mt-3" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is my router code within the users router:

```
router.post('/register', function(request, response, next) {
  console.log(request);
  console.log(request.body)
  response.render('register', { 'title': 'Register' });
});
```

Here is relevant output on the console:

```
console.log(request); output shortened this is just the tail.      
  _startAt: [ 299545, 483820242 ],
  _startTime: 2018-09-20T16:08:59.366Z,
  _remoteAddress: '::1',
  body: {},
  _body: true,
  length: undefined,
  read: [Function],
  secret: undefined,
  cookies: {},
  signedCookies: {},
  route:
   Route {
     path: '/register',
     stack: [ [Object] ],
     methods: { post: true } } }
{}
POST /users/register 200 21.906 ms - 2361
```

app.js code:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.use(function(request, response, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

app.use(function(error, request, response, next) {
  response.locals.message = error.message;
  response.locals.error = request.app.get('env') === 'development' ? error : {};
  response.status(error.status || 500);
  response.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Things I've tried:

- different browsers
- different routes
- writing simpler forms from scratch
- formidable instead of body-parser

I'm pretty sure at this point that it's a problem with the ejs form because the body object in the request is always empty.

Comment: Can you please post your `app.js` code as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `<input>` elements in the form must have a `name` attribute defined, not just `id`.

Comment: Thanks! Added name attributes and everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Another common error when using express, make sure you use `body-parser`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser
`i.e`

```js
    const router = express();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    router.use(bodyParser.json())
    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));
```

Comment: Should not be required as a separate import as of [v4.16](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.jso)

Comment: Just to Note that `body-parser` has been deprecated as of  Express 4.16+

Answer (score 0):

The other answer pointed out what you're missing and I updated your .ejs code to show you correct way of posting a html form:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="/users/register">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="confirmPassword" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Re-enter Password">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-dark mt-3" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You can either do the above or handle the submission with javascript/jquery if you're submitting a more complex form or need some sort of validation on fields.

See this answer: [Submit a form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)