# Get submit button value from multiple buttons php

Tags: php, input, dynamic, menu, submit

I have a dynamic menu inside a form element code is here

```
<form method="GET" action="index.php">
<?php
display_menu(); // this function generates menu items
?>
</form>
```

after the menu is generated every menu item is a submit button of the above form I want to get input of a single element by name or id attribute of submit button, and load a post from database.

```
<form method="GET" action="index.php">
<input type="submit" name="page-1" id="page-1" value="page-1">
<input type="submit" name="page-2" id="page-2" value="page-2">
<input type="submit" name="page-3" id="page-3" value="page-3">
<input type="submit" name="page-4" id="page-4" value="page-4">
</form>
```

so when any input button is pressed the function display_post() is called. Code of the function is as follows:-

```
function display_post(){
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'posts') or die('cannot connect');
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' ){
$blog_post_id = $_GET["id"]; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts where id='blog_post_id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('cannot load');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if($row > 0){
echo '<div>'.$row['content'].'</div>';
}else echo 'no posts';
}
}
}
```

However, the `display_post()` method is called inside a content tag whereas the `display_menu()` is called inside another div.
So the problem is I'm unable to get the id of the to submit button any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Which Id? DO you mean input value?

Comment: Using unsanitized GET parameter is not recommended and can lead to sqlinjections. You should make sure `$blog_post_id` is a numeric value first.

Comment: page-1, page-2, page-3  is your blog_post_id ?

Comment: We can't get input fields by `id`, we get input fields by `name` as you trying to get `$_GET["id"];`

Comment: I have tried $_GET["name"]; too but the same notice undefined

Comment: Please get it by name like `page-1` or  `page-2`, or `page-3` or `page-4` these are field name. the name is the field attribute.

Comment: I think you first read these articles https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-form-handling.php and https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the submit button you will get all inputs values of the form.

Do one thing put this statement  `print_r($_GET);exit;` in `display_post()` as a first line and see what you get after clicking on submit button.

**Note:** 1. you want to get the value of clicked button then you should use javascript or jQuery and Ajax.
2. You can not get input fields value by fields `ID`. 
ex. if we have field `<input type="submit" name="page-1" id="page-1" value="page-1">`
then we can get its value as:

```
echo $_GET['page-1'];
```

`page-1` is the input field name.

Comment: see these solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery and
https://www.johnmorrisonline.com/jquery-tutorial-submit-a-form-and-post-data-using-jquery-and-ajax/

Comment: I put the variable print_r($_GET) after the line $blog_post_id = $_GET["id"]; and get output Array ( [9] => html )

Comment: put it as a first line in function `print_r($_GET) ;exit();` then see th result would be `array("page-1"=>page-1,"page-2"=>page-2,"page-3"=page-3, "page-4"=>page-4)`.

Comment: same output and have value as 
Array ( [9] => html ) but I am unable to collect value in variable $blog_post_id = $_GET["id"] or even using array index $blog_post_id = $_GET["0"]

Answer (score 0):

If I am guessing right what is your difficulty then

```
$blog_post_id = $_GET['id']; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM blog_posts where id='".$blog_post_id."' ";//I modified this line
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('cannot load');
```

Comment: it says Notice: Undefined index: id on this line

Comment: Yes right, please see your input fields name these are `page-1`, `page-2`, `page-3`, `page-4`.

Comment: @sudarshan, we can not get fields value by attributes like `id` or `name` as you are trying `$_GET["id"]; `. this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make  5 different forms for each button and change the action to

```
action="index.php?id=1"
```

Then use `$_GET['id']`

Also change `id='blog_post_id' "   to id='$blog_post_id' "`