# submit a form using jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to submit a form using button click `result_submit` event. Here I am using type as `button` instead of `submit`.

**Reason for changing button type from  submit to button:**
I was trying to show some hidden div after the form submit, but I couldn't achieve that using a submit function. when I changed it type=button, I was able to do it with onclick function.

The problem I am facing here is I am not getting any results now.As soon as I change button type back to `submit`, it will work. Any suggestions here to resolve this ?

form html:

```
<form method="post" id="form_result" action="">

<----some options to select here->


    <div class="form-group">

    <button  onclick="show_result()" type="button" name="result_submit" id="result_submit"  style="display: none;margin:1%;" >Submit</button>

    </div>


</form>
```

Jquery:

```
function show_result() {

document.getElementById('form_result').submit();

}
```

Php (file name : functions.php):

```
if(isset($_POST['result_submit'])){


include_once 'dbConnection.php';

<--some codes here----->

if ($_POST['result_options'] == 'Current_Month'){   

<---some codes here----->
}
}
```

***Important Note:-***

my PHP codes are on default WordPress `functions.php` file. I added action for form, but not working.

Also tried to move the PHP code from `functions.php` to a new file. that is also not working. I think there is something wrong with my other codes.

Comment: use type="submit" in button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit a form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

Comment: Is there any error showing in console?

Comment: if you are going to submit form and not using Ajax to process form. it seem unnecessary then

Comment: @SureshSuthar: No errors

Comment: @acr Not sure why there is `display: none;` on the button...

Comment: @CodeThing button will be displayed only after user select all options before that

Comment: @acr Ah. Makes sense then...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. On click function , it will fetch form_data and serializes form values

```
    $('#result_submit').click(function () {

            var form_data = $("#form_result");
            var data = form_data.serialize();
            console.log(data );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove `style="display: none;margin:1%;"` from your `result_submit` button otherwise, it will be not visible.

Your Code is working as it should be, but the problem is with your php file `functions.php`.

In it you are checking condition like `if(isset($_POST['result_submit'])){`, so condition **returns true** when you use `input type='submit'`, but **returns false** when you use `<button>`, read below for reason.

it is not working Because **named input** `type="submit"` will be also **submitted together with the other form's named fields** while a **named** `type="button"` **will not be submitted**.

In the example below, the `button` with `name='button'` **WON'T get submitted**, while the `input type=submit` with `name='submit'` **WILL get submitted**.

sample form.html

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">

<!-- this won't get submitted despite being named -->
<button type="button" name="button">Normal Button</button>
<!-- this also won't get submitted despite being named -->
<input type="button" name="button1" value="Button1" >

<!-- this one does; so the input's TYPE is important! -->
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Button">

</form>
```

So change your `functions.php` file as below and it will work as you expect:

```
if( isset($_POST) && $_POST){

 include_once 'dbConnection.php';

 //some code here

 if (isset($_POST['result_options']) && $_POST['result_options'] == 'Current_Month'){   

   //some codes here

 }
}
```

It will work using your same above code, just change your functions.php file or file to which you are submitting your form.