# $(element).click() not triggering even inside $(function() {})

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I have an input element (Dropzone) that's hidden, and is written in the original html's body (was not appended).

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <form action="/uploadProfile" method="post" class="dropzone" id="uploadProfileDropzone"></form>
</div>
```

Now inside my .js script, I'm trying:

```
 $(function() {
      $('#uploadProfileDropzone').click()
 })
```

And nothing happens. However, if I'm calling `$('#uploadProfileDropzone').click()` inside Chrome's console, it works.

What could possibly be the problem?

**EDIT**:

Problem might be that I'm trying to call the function before my Dropzone has initialized. Is there a way to know when this happens?

However, even when trying:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
         $('#uploadProfileDropzone').click() 
    }, 5000)
})
```

Which is a lot after the page fully loads, still nothing happens

**SOLUTION**:

It turns out that some (or even most of the) browsers block such activity. It's pretty obvious why, looking back at it now. My intention was to navigate to a page that once ready, opens a file dialog for a profile upload action. It seems logically correct to block such action from a user experience point of view, as it can lead to spam and undesired activity from websites. I solved it by displaying a simple popup box on load, that forces the user to press a button, that in turn calls `$('#uploadProfileDropzone').click()` and it worked.

Comment: That's a form, not an input. It's unusual to have a click handler for an entire `<form>`. Are you sure this is the same element you have a click handler for?

Comment: what would be the exact working when you 'click' ?

Comment: it might be a case where you're dropzone has not been initialised yet when you call `$('#uploadProfileDropzone').click()`

Comment: Wouldnt you need a submit? `$('#uploadProfileDropzone').submit()`

Comment: Please try below code:
`$('#uploadProfileDropzone').on('click',function(){
    write your code
});`

Comment: Are You sure that dropzone is initialized BEFORE .click() call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit a form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery)

Comment: how can i know when my dropzone finished to initalize?

Comment: @UFCInsider, can't remember if dropzone has an event for that, however I would suggest just initialising it programatically instead, it'll give you more control overall.

Comment: @fixatd can you post an answer as an example? all i need from this dropzone is the ability to manually trigger the file dialog after initializing is done

Comment: Dropzone doesn't appear to have an event for initialised: https://www.dropzonejs.com/#events

Comment: You could try with a simple `setTimeout` - if dropzone inits with doc.ready, then it might just be that it's in the doc.ready queue to run after your doc.ready.  `$(function() { setTimeout(function() { $('#uploadProfileDropzone').click(); }, 100); });`

Comment: tried already, not working

Comment: `click` on form tag? You should add a button to submit the form.

Comment: @SumeshTG how come it works on Chrome's console? i don't think it's about that

Comment: @UFCInsider posted an answer about what you were asking about

Comment: @fixatd checking it out the moment i get on my laptop again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that some (or even most of the) browsers block such activity. It's pretty obvious why, looking back at it now. My intention was to navigate to a page that once ready, opens a file dialog for a profile upload action. It seems logically correct to block such action from a user experience point of view, as it can lead to spam and undesired activity from websites. I solved it by displaying a simple popup box on load, that forces the user to press a button, that in turn calls `$('#uploadProfileDropzone').click()` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You possibly have two options:

1) Programatically create your dropzone

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
let csvDropzone = new Dropzone("#uploadProfileDropzone", {
  paramName: "file",
  init: function() {
      $('#uploadProfileDropzone').click();
  }
});
```

```html
<div style="display: none;">
    <form action="/uploadProfile" method="post" class="dropzone" id="uploadProfileDropzone">
    </form>
</div>
```

2) You can try using [init](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-init) configuration method directly without initialising the dropzone in your JS code:

```
// Taken from the dropzone config page
Dropzone.options.uploadProfileDropzone = {
  init: function() {
      $('#uploadProfileDropzone').click();
  }
};
```

Comment: tried both options, didn't work 
i'm starting to think maybe the browser is blocking such action? navigativing to a url that automatically opens a file dialog

Comment: might be the case, have you tried in a different browser?

Comment: yep, that was the case. i solved it by letting the user click a button before opening the file dialog

Answer (score -3):

you should use document ready event (code works once elements are initialized)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#uploadProfileDropzone').click(function(){
        // Do something here
    });
});
```

OR

```
$('#uploadProfileDropzone').on('click',function(){ write your code here });
```

Comment: `$(function() {...})` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {...})`

Comment: In addition to above, OP is *firing* the click event handler, not creating a new on, so `.on` is totally inappropriate here.