# Posting form data which contains a number of Select List inputs not posting anything

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a situation where I am creating a HTML form using Bootstrap 3, Ajax result and dataTables. Depending on the result of the Ajax call the form contains a number of rows of data. Each row has a select list drop-down which allows the user to select the order for each record prior to saving.

The code that produces the "select list drop-downs"  only showing  part of the form is:

```
<form  name="Form12" id="orderSave" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" >
<input name="MM_insert" type="hidden" value="Form12">
<input type="hidden" name="GroupID" id="OrderGroupID">
"<td align='center' style='color:#333;font-size:0.8em;'> \
<select name='ViewOrder[]' id='ViewOrder'  style='color:#333;font-size:0.8em;'required > \
<option value='0' selected>0</option> \
<option value='1'>1</option> \
<option value='2'>2</option> \
<option value='3'>3</option> \
<option value='4'>4</option> \
<option value='5'>5</option> \
<option value='6'>6</option> \
<option value='7'>7</option> \
<option value='8'>8</option> \
<option value='9'>9</option> \
<option value='10'>10</option> \
</select> \
</td>" +
<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs submit-button" type="submit" >Save</button>
</form>
```

When the form is submitted non of the options selected in the "name='ViewOrder[]' are passed to the data submit script.

Data submit script:

```
$("#orderSave").submit(function(event){
  var group_id = document.getElementById("OrderGroupID").value;
  console.log("GroupID: " , group_id);
  event.preventDefault(); 
  var form = $('form')[12];
  var formData = new FormData(form);
  formData.append("GroupID", group_id);
  console.log("Form Data: " , formData);
  $.ajax({
    url:"update_order.php",
    data: formData,
    method:"POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
  }).done(function(response){ 
    $('#view_order_Modal').modal("hide");
  });
});
```

Server side script:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
require_once('../../../../../Connections/conn.php');
print_r($_POST['ViewOrder ']);

if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

$groupid = trim($_POST['GroupID']);
$OrderArray = array();
$OrderArray = $_POST['ViewOrder'];
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE Signage_timeline SET DisplayOrder=%s WHERE CarouselGroupID ='".$groupid ."'",
GetSQLValueString($_POST['DisplayOrder'] = $Order, "text"));
mysql_select_db($database_vex, $conn);
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

In the console (Chrome) apart from displaying the expected "GroupID" nothing else is displayed. In the script that processes the data I have "print_r ($_POST)", which display only the "GroupID".

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: mysql_query has been deprecated .Please avoid this usage refer https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I make this work:

```
$(document).on('click','#orderSave', function(event){ 
$("#OrderSave").serialize(); 
event.preventDefault(); 
$.ajax({ 
type: "POST", 
url: 'update_order.php', 
data: $("#OrderSave").serialize(), 
}).done(function(response){ 
$('#view_order_Modal').modal("hide"); 
}); 
}); 

Then in the process script I have:


if (!isset($_SESSION)) { 
session_start(); 
} 
require_once('../../../../../Connections/vex.php'); 
$RecordArray = array(); 
$RecordArray = $_POST['id']; 
$OrderArray = array();  
$OrderArray = $_POST['ViewOrder']; 

$id_array = $_POST['id']; 
$name_array = $_POST['name']; 
$age_array = $_POST['age']; 
for ($i = 0; $i < count($RecordArray); $i++) { 
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($RecordArray[$i]); 
$order = mysql_real_escape_string($OrderArray[$i]); 

$updateSQL = "UPDATE Signage_timeline SET DisplayOrder= '".$order."' WHERE RecordID ='".$id ."'"; 
mysql_select_db($database_navex, $vex); 
$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $vex) or die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $("#orderSave").submit(function(e) {

        //prevent Default functionality
        e.preventDefault();


        //do your own request an handle the results
        $.ajax({
                url: 'update_order.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: $("#orderSave").serialize(),
                 cache: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#view_order_Modal').modal("hide");
                }
        });

    });
```

refer [Submit a form using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200266/submit-a-form-using-jquery/16228922)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. In the console when the form is submitted I see "MM_insert=Form12&GroupID=506592&ViewOrder%5B%5D=1&ViewOrder%5B%5D=2". But, in the Script that processes the submitted data the "print_r ($_POST) array is empty. any ideas?

Comment: I did change the data: $("#orderSave").serialize(), prior to testing.  "print_r ($_POST) array is empty.

Comment: in update_order.php <?php extract($_POST); echo $GroupID; ?> try this ,if the solution satisfies you expectation  please approve it,thanks

Comment: I inserted "echo "Hello world";" in the script that prsesses the posted data and the result is: Hello worldarray(0) {}. So I know the ajax post is pointing to the correct file. I think there is something simple here but what I don;t know. I don't normally have this issue.

Comment: have you tried this '<?php extract($_POST); echo $GroupID; ?>' instead of echo "Hello World"

Comment: I take it extract($_POST); echo $GroupID;  goes in the script that is processes the data i.e. update_order.php? I have tried that and it display nothing.

Comment: since ViewOrder is an array try print_r($_POST['ViewOrder '])

Comment: sorry i am not able to figure out the server side script.please post it so that i can find the issue,since the ajax request has been passed,there is no problem in js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190766/discussion-between-deepak-and-dcjones).

Comment: Hi, I found a solution and have posted it in the chat we were having.

Answer (score -1):

Simply serialize the form then post through ajax

like wise

```
 data: $("form").serialize()
```

Something like this

```
$("#orderSave").submit(function(event){

  event.preventDefault(); 

  alert($("#orderSave").serialize());

});
```

Comment: I am using serilize as per DeePak answer but the processing script is not displaying any data if I do a print_r ($_POST).I have also tried extract($_POST); echo $GroupID; with the same result.

Comment: you are not understanding his problem.the problem is in server side code